How to check if a USB conector is broken
Suppose we want to check that usb port is working. we can do the continuity test with a multimiter.We connect the positive part of the  multimiter to positive part of the connector and we do the same with the negative part.Now suppose that the multimiter gave us a bepp. How can we know that the bepp is due to close circuit of the USB port instead of a the closed circuit of the internal part of the computer?

By "bepp" do you mean "beep". Also you should search for "USB port tester" they are very common and cheap.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

for the signal lines, functional test is an "eye diagram"

Dealing with basic USB, as in USB 2.0, there are four wires, Power +, Ground, Signal + and Signal -.  Testing the power + and ground are easy enough, just look at the voltage.  Anything else is not so simple.  Whenever testing a cable, the best bet is to plug into both ends of the cable so you can test continuity.  Measuring the resistance of all four wires and checking to make sure they are not shorted internally will give you some information.
Meanwhile, USB moves data, lots of data and fast, too.  If the insulation is questionable or the wires frayed, there is a good chance, it will test out fine with a multimeter and be bad.  It may work fine with a low speed device like, say, a keyboard and not function with an external disk drive.
The short version, you can test, it might even give useful results.
